# Bermudan pricing in Black-Scholes

Tags: american-options, numerical-methods, bermudan

Is there an "analytical" method to price American options (approximated as daily Bermudans) in the Black-Scholes model using backward induction?

$$V_T(S) = \max(K-S, 0)$$
$$V_{T-\Delta t}(S) = \max(K-S, \operatorname{BS}(S, K, \Delta t, \sigma,r, q))$$

Then you could find the exercise boundary point (probably numerically) and knowing that, analyically integrate the piecewise function back another step to time $T-2\Delta t$...

Comment: Perhaps Lord et al.'s (2008) [CONV method](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/070683878) or Fang and Oosterlee's (2009) [COS method](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00211-009-0252-4)? Both methods rely on backward induction and apply to a wide class of models. You can then use Richardson extrapolation to get American option prices from the prices of Bermudan options.